# Cannot move the search bar after the logo

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, search

I want to move the search bar right after the logo and sign-in, and sign-up link next to search bar. I have used the below instruction in my theme xml file but its not working.

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

**Code in default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="default_head_blocks" />
   <body>    
      <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
      <move element="authorization-link-login" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search" />
   </body>
</page>
```

**I'm getting as below but I want to show as search bar after the logo and signin and signup next to search bar:**
[image]

Please help.

Comment: you are share me screenshort?? what want to.

Comment: If you use the custom theme, please share the code of default.xml file which is in Magento_Theme module of your custom theme.

Comment: @madani, I have added the code which I have used in default.xml. Please check and help

Answer (score 0):

You can try below XML

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <container name="link.login" htmlTag="ul" htmlClass="login-link" before="minicart" />
</referenceContainer>

<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
<move element="authorization-link" destination="link.login"/>
```

Add below css

```
.page-header .block.block-search {
    float: left;
}
.page-header .login-link {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this will help you..!